# Is possible to reuse complex html markup with knockout.js inside the same page?

Tags: templates, knockout.js

I've created a quite complex custom list using knockout.js that rappresents settings for a specific continent.
 The view model has more than 20 observable variables and some computed functions that bind the logic. The html has some nested foreach as the original data came from JSON objects.

Now I have to create this settings for each continent - Is there a way I can reuse the code written without enlaging the view model and copy all the markup 6 more times ? All the settings must be in one page.

Thanks

Comment: Did you learn about Knockout [templates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html)? They are intended to do exactly what you want, aren't they?

Comment: yes, you're right - my only doubt was all the computed functions that I didn't moved to the object